# Running a remote SQL query over SSH

Tags: mysql, ssh, bash

I am attempting to execute a MySQL query on a remote server over ssh. Here is the command I have:

```
ssh -p 2020 mysql@mysql1.local.mydomain.com 'mysql --compress --secure-auth --database operations --execute \'INSERT INTO `ops`.`accounts` (`alias`, `id`, `web_server`, `mysql_server`) VALUES (\'thisisatest\', \'act_67vhVnS30bV\', \'web2\', \'mysql1\');\''
```

That should be right, but I am getting:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite the command like:

> ssh -p 2020 mysql@mysql1.local.mydomain.com "mysql --compress
>   --secure-auth --database operations --execute 'INSERT INTO \`ops\`.\`accounts\` (\`alias\`, \`id\`, \`web_server\`,
>   \`mysql_server\`) VALUES ('thisisatest', 'act_67vhVnS30bV', 'web2',
>   'mysql1');'"

Use double quotes for the complete SSH command. Single quotes don't require to be escaped. You need to escape the backticks \`.

Comment: since double-escaping can be quite troublesome but is occasionally necessary with MySQL statements run over SSH, I would suggest dumping the entire remote `mysql --[...]` command into a `mysqlcommand` file and just running `ssh -p 2020 mysql@mysql1.local.mydomain.com < mysqlcommand`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't dump the SQL into a file, since it is built up dynamically in a shell script. Unless, there is a way I am not aware of.

Comment: That's what pipes are for...